# state in parent component is not updated when method fire from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

there is one issue in my react code that I would be pleased if someone can help me with.
I have a child component that emits the method and I use that method in my parent component. Also in the parent component, there is a state, that whenever the method emits I want to change the value of the state.
Here is the code :

```
 const [color, setColor] = useState("red");

const selectColor= (colorName) => {
setColor("blue");
console.log("color : ", color);
 }
  <Child onChangeColor={selectColor} />
```

here is the problem. when I call the method I change the value of color to "blue" but for the first time the value does not change but the second time that I call the function again, the value is updated to the "blue".
where did I do wrong?
I would be appreciated If anyone can explain it to me.

Bests.

Comment: Please prepare not working example

Comment: post the code of Child component as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. SetColor will not update the state immediately, so console.log will log the previous value. You need to log it like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
console.log(color)
  }, [color])
```

useEffect will console.log the color value once color value finishes changing.